# Why is my Javascript and JQuery scripting not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking at another question and saw that they had been told, when their Javascript was not working, to put a function that started on loading of the page.

I was trying to use this code:(well, not exactly this code, but something like it)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function doThisWhenLoaded(){
    var code = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    code.append("<p>Yes it did.</p>");
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="doThisWhenLoaded">
        <h1 style="font-family:sans-serif;">Did it work?</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And nothing happened. All that it did was show the h1 code that I put in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Comment: Also, you're using jQuery's `append()` incorrectly. It must be applied to a jQuery object (`$('body').append()`).

Comment: Ok, I will try that, because I just noticed that I was using JQuery on an element selected by Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already including jQuery try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var code = $("body");
    code.append("<p>Yes it did.</p>");
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <h1 style="font-family:sans-serif;">Did it work?</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the parenthesis to call the function in the `body` element's `onload` attribute:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function doThisWhenLoaded() {
      //Modified the two lines below slightly
      var code = document.querySelector("body");
      code.innerHTML += "<p>Yes it did.</p>";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="doThisWhenLoaded()">
  <h1 style="font-family:sans-serif;">Did it work?</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

A better/cleaner way to achieve the same thing would be to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. Something like below:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", appendHtml.call(null, {
  selector: 'body',
  html: '<p>Yes it did.</p>'
}));

function appendHtml(config) {
  document.querySelector(config.selector).innerHTML += config.html;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-family:sans-serif;">Did it work?</h1>
```

Comment: I actually was trying to use JQuery, not just Javascript. The only reason this question's title contains the word Javascript is because I was confused and trying to use JQuery on a element selected by Javascript and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Two reason why it doesn't work:

- To select the `body` you have to use `document.body` or `$("body")` (in jQuery)
- And you forgot to add parentheses to your function call `doThisWhenLoaded()`

---

Here is the code corrected:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function doThisWhenLoaded(){
    $("body").append("<p>Yes it did.</p>");
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="doThisWhenLoaded()">
        <h1 style="font-family:sans-serif;">Did it work?</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```